# Hiding and Showing controls in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiview, xamarin.ios

I am a Xamarin.iOS beginner. I don't have much iOS native experience too. I am trying to hide and show a UIView which contains a UILabel and a UITextField. Though the hidden property is set to true for the view, it still occupies space in the screen. How do I remove this space? If I try to set the width constraints to 0 to hide it and then later, set it back to its original value to show it, it doesn't work. It continues to remain at 0.

Another question - will the view retain its state and behaviour when toggling on and off its visibility?

Thanks in advance for all the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code it's difficult to tell the solutions. But from your question I can see few solutions like:

1. You can try changing constraint in main thread and after changing constraint you need to call `LayoutIfNeeded()`

   `[Foundation.Export("layoutIfNeeded")]
    public virtual Void LayoutIfNeeded ()`
2. Other than that you can use `horizontal UIStackView` which will make `UIView`'s width to 0 while hiding and back to original while showing.

Comment: I used horizontal stack view to redesign my UI. It works. Thanks @ArnabHore

Answer (score 1):

Even though you set the control's `Hidden` to true, it still exists there just can't be seen. So if your second control's constraints depend on the first one, it will not change its position.

> set it back to its original value to show it, it doesn't work. It continues to remain at 0.

Which kind of constraints are you using?

If you use `NSLayoutAnchor`, you should disable the previous constraint before you want to modify it. For example:

```
//Define a field
NSLayoutConstraint WidthConstraint = null;

//When you want to modify the width, try to disable the previous one
if (WidthConstraint != null)
{
    WidthConstraint.Active = false;
}
WidthConstraint = Control.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(0);
WidthConstraint.Active = true;
```

If you use `NSLayoutConstraint`, you can change the constant directly:

```
foreach (NSLayoutConstraint constraints in Control.Constraints)
{
    if (constraints.FirstItem.IsEqual(Control) && constraints.FirstAttribute.Equals(NSLayoutAttribute.Width))
    {
        constraints.Constant = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LandLu-MSFT. I am using NSLayoutConstraint. I will check this out.