# UIView is not hiding when I add it programmatically to UIstackview

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uistackview

I am new to xamarin ios and `xcode`. I have a tableview cell which has `UILabel`, a switch and a horizontal `UIStackView` (Center alignment, Distribution - Equal spacing). I have created a default `UIView` containing a textfield. This default view is added to the `UIStackView` in `xib`. In my program, I want to add a similar view to the right of the existing view and align it horizontally. I am also keeping a list of all input views added.

My problem is I am not able to hide the newly added views. If I remove the width constraints, then the width varies depending on placeholder text. If I remove the leading anchor constraints, then they are not aligned uniformly.

when I try to set the hidden property for the newly added view (subview of `UIStackView`), it hides it but the space is left as is. I tried setting the constraints to false, used it with `LayoutIfNeeded()` but that doesn't help either.

Any other options available to actually hide the subview??

```
 UIView newView = new UIView();
 InputStack.AddArrangedSubview(newView);

 var newInput = new UITextField();
  newView.AddSubview(newInput);
  newInput.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
  newInput.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(175).Active = true;
  newInput.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(35).Active = true;
  newInput.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(newView.TopAnchor).Active = true;
  newInput.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(InputList.Last().InputTextField.TrailingAnchor, 30).Active = true;
```

Comment: Have you tried using the fill equally distribution and not adding the text field inside the new view and just adding it straight to the stack view?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/uistackview/) about how to use `UIStackView`.

If you want to add items from left to right, there's no need to add the `newView` first then put your Control in the `newView`. You can directly put the `newInput` in the `UIStackView`. Also because you have used the horizontal StackView whose subViews will layout from leading to trailing automatically, the top and leading constraints can be omitted. Only width constraint is needed.

From your code, you use `NSLayoutAnchor` to add constraints. You should disable the previous constraint before you want to modify it:

```
//Define a field
NSLayoutConstraint WidthConstraint = null;

//When you want to modify the width, try to disable the previous one
if (WidthConstraint != null)
{
    WidthConstraint.Active = false;
}
WidthConstraint = Control.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(0);
WidthConstraint.Active = true;
```

You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49165964/8354952) for more details.

Or you can also remove the control directly. Then when you want to show it, add it again.